# TLS handshake error: read tcp in NATS server K8 pod

Tags: tls1.2, nats.io, nats-streaming-server, nats-jetstream

I have deployed NATS using k8 repo `https://nats-io.github.io/k8s/helm/charts/`.
I have enabled TLS and jetstream in the value.yaml as listed below

```
config:
  cluster:
    enabled: true
    replicas: 3
    port: 6222
  jetstream:
    enabled: true
    fileStore:
      pvc:
        size: 10Gi
  nats:
    tls:
      enabled: true
      merge: {
        verify: true,
        cert_file: '/mnt/nats-certificate/nats-playground-server.crt',
        key_file: '/mnt/nats-certificate/nats-playground-server.key',
        ca_file: '/mnt/nats-certificate/rootCA-playground.crt',
        timeout: 50
      }
  
podTemplate:
  topologySpreadConstraints:
    kubernetes.io/hostname:
      maxSkew: 1
      whenUnsatisfiable: DoNotSchedule
  patch:
  - op: add
    path: /spec/volumes/-
    value:
      name: nats-certificate-volume
      csi:
        driver: secrets-store.csi.k8s.io
        readOnly: true
        volumeAttributes:
          secretProviderClass: 'nats-certificate'

service:
  merge:
    spec:
      type: LoadBalancer

# promExporter:
#   enabled: true
#   podMonitor:
#     enabled: true

container:
  image:
    repository: nats
    image: 2.10.11-alpine
  patch:
  - op: add
    path: /volumeMounts/-
    value:
      name: nats-certificate-volume
      mountPath: /mnt/nats-certificate

reloader:
  patch:
  - op: add
    path: /volumeMounts/-
    value:
      name: nats-certificate-volume
      mountPath: /mnt/nats-certificate
```

Issue is my Nats pod is see TLS handhshake error logs like below:-

```
 TLS handshake error: read tcp 10.244.2.29:4222->10.240.0.8:51404: read: connection reset by peer
```

`10.244.2.29` is my Nats pod Ip and `10.240.0.8` is the node ip in k8. I have not connected any client to my nats server, still I see the TLS handshake error. I'm confused why there is TLS connection being made between the NATS server pod and the k8 node.If so, I'm not sure about how can I resolve the TLS handshake error.